# On the street or on street

Tags: articles, definite-article

Why do we use definite article with "street"? 
When i say

> They found a wallet on the street

I don't mean any specific street, so shy do we use "the" , I've never heard anyone saying

> I found a wallet on a street

Answer (score 1):

I've no research to back this up, but my guess is that for most of the history of the English language, most native speakers lived in places where there was only *one* road/street in the local area anyway. Hence *originally* it was quite natural to use the definite article in such contexts, and that conventional usage has simply persisted until the present day.

By the same token, even when public transport become widely available, for most people there would usually only be one contextually-relevant ***bus, train*** that they might use. Hence *I go to school on **the** bus, [Let **the** train take the strain](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/let-the-train-take-the-strain.679586/)* - but note that it's always *I'll take **a** taxi / cab* (there are usually either no taxis at all or *several* in any given area).

Answer (score 0):

You may not specify the street name, but you are also describing whereabouts the wallet was lying - it wasn't in a tree on the street, it was literally *on* the street.

> They found a wallet on the street.

Consider these examples:

> I was walking along **a** street when I found a wallet lying on **the** sidewalk.
>
> I was walking along **the** street when I saw a wallet on top of **a** parked car.

You can see from these examples that you can refer to "a street" down which you were walking on and still use the definite article to describe the state in which you found the wallet; likewise, you can say "the street" but use an indefinite article for the location of the wallet. This is because there is only one sidewalk but potentially many cars.